# Please help identify the font of the "Voyage to the bottom of the sea" tv series logo

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking for a font similar or identical to this one:

[image: FONT DEMO]

I search with "what is the font?" but I could not find anyone. 
The most similar that I found was:

http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Plastic_Beach.htm

but the uppercase are lowercase but bigger.

Underwater and Underwater love are more different.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Note that there are 5 'T's in this image and they are all entirely different. That's a pretty good sign that this is hand lettering--not a font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you're not going to find this one. It looks to me this started out as a straight or semi-wiggly font, which has been custom-made into this logo.